# Worshiping one God at a time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an article on "God, Types of Worship" and I'm looking for a term which describes worshiping a single god at a time.

That is, given that different gods exist, the practise of worshiping only one of these at a given time, then moving on to worship another god. The focus of worship changes, but the worshiper's overall religion remains the same.

*Monotheism* is not the word I am looking for. I know the term but I can't recall it.

____ is the practise of worshiping one god of many extant gods, one at a time.

Comment: **henotheism**, n. A form of faith which, although recognizing the existence (or potential existence) of several gods, makes only one god the centre of its worship. -- 1860   F. M. Müller  *The latter form of faith, the belief in One God, is properly called Monotheism, whereas the term of Henotheism would best express the faith in a single god.* -- 1879   P. Le P. Renouf *The nature of Henotheism as distinct from Monotheism was explained in last year's lectures as a phase of religious thought in which the individual gods invoked are not conceived as limited by the power of others.*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The term is **Kathenotheism.** It was coined by Max Muller from Greek *kath' hen* "one by one" i.e. *kata-* "according to" + *en-* "one" plus *-theism*.

So, in Kathenotheism (it is not a religion in itself, it is use to denote a particular type of religion) you worship one God head **at a time** **and then move ahead** to worship another Gods (Trinity)/Deities in same sect, or religion.

Reference from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathenotheism

> Müller coined the term in reference to the Vedas, where he explained each deity is treated as supreme in turn.

Please note, Kathenotheism is different from Polytheism. In Polytheism, we worship all Gods (Trinity) and other deities **at the same time**, but in Kathenotheism we worship ONLY one God **at a time,** **then move ahead** to worship another one.

Also, note that Kathenotheism is different from Henotheism. Henotheist person, worships only one God, and neglects all other. Henotheist, does know, that there exists other Gods and Deities, but she/he worships only ONE God. The word Henotheism was also coined by Max Muller.

I don't want to complicate things for you, but I think you should also know, the difference between Monotheism and Henotheism. Monotheism is different from Henotheism, in a way, that *in* Monotheism you know that there is only **one God** and no other i.e. no concept of Trinity or deities.

Comment: Henotheism ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henotheism ) or even monolatry have wider currency and are not dependent on Max Muller's particular viewpoint.

Comment: IMO, "no concept of Trinity" is pointlessly argumentative.  Christians hold that there is only one God.  Claiming that it is not monotheism seems to incite (pointless) arguments over definitions.

Comment: @Spitemaster Concept of Trinity also exist in Hinduism. My answer is not related to Christianity.

Comment: The Hindu *Trimutri* is [different to the Christian Trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18221), This answer may be correct in terms of Trimutri, but it is wrong in respect of the Trinity. @Spitemaster is correct: using the correct language (especially on a language site) is of paramount importance.

Comment: @AndrewLeach since when did this post became specific to Christianity? **Either the question nor answer talks about Christianity.** Also, what about all other world religions who believe in trinity or multiple God heads. Why one would specifically care to draft answer keeping Christianity in focus? And it is almost 2 years now, so why bring this unrelated issue now?

Comment: It's come to notice now because of flags on comments. The use of the word Trinity is a problem, because it has a particular meaning. (It may have more than one meaning; it's problematic because of its meaning in Christianity.) If Christianity is not relevant to the answer, I would suggest that the word be replaced with *Trimurti;* and if it doesn't need to be there at all, then complete removal is probably the best solution. At present, a principal meaning of the word *Trinity* means this answer gives wrong information, because Christianity is not polytheistic, which using *Trinity* implies.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There is no English equivalent word for Sanskrit word Trimurti. Closest  is Trinity. Concept is also quite similar, out of three two are seen as [father and son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma#/media/File:Sheshashayi_Vishnu.jpg) and third as supreme spirit. I don't know before this that one can use Sanskrit word on English.SE as well. So, using correct language on English.SE is of utter importance. Hence, I refrained from using Sanskrit word while drafting my answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Also, the word in focus is Kathenotheism. If we go by this concept then there are so many words in English dictionary which should be used only in relation to Christianity e.g. ecumenical. Its primary meaning is very christian in nature.

Comment: Well found.  However, this term exhibits a misunderstanding of polytheism.  In the versions of polytheism with which I am familiar, notably that of ancient Greece, acts of worship were conducted in relation to one of them at a time.  So there was no need for a special word.  Often the local patron deity (Athena for Athens, Poseidon for Corinth; Sparta greedily had two, Ares - of course - and Artemis Orthia).  But they never had to share the sacrificial offering with other gods.

Answer (score 6):

Is [**monolatry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolatry) the word you're looking for?

Monolatry, in contrast to monotheism, refers to the *worship* of a single god, without denying the validity of others.

Comment: You are correct about Monolartry, but that is not the word which describes worshiping God "one after another" in same sect or religion. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: @GATECSE You're right, it's not exactly what you asked for. It is, however, close enough that I think it may be useful to others who find your question seeking a similar word.

Answer (score 6):

There are some good answers already offered, and I was going to jump in with monolatry myself. However I noticed that none of them actually quite meet the specifics of your question:

> given that different gods exist, the practise of worshiping only one
>   of these at a given time, then moving on to worship another god.

- **Kathenotheism** is somewhat similar to what you want, but doesn't actually mean you only worship one god; the kathenotheist may worship many gods, but believes only one is supreme. The ruler of the pantheon is what changes from time to time, not the object of worship.
- **Monolatry** doesn't move on to other gods. The monolatrist believes in the existence of many gods, but worships only one.
- **Summodeism** is another related concept; the summodeist accepts the existence of multiple gods, but believes that they are all aspects or emanations of one supreme being. He adopts different forms of worship according to which aspect he wish to appeal to, but considers them all the same being.
- **Henotheism** is difficult because it is used in different ways by different authors. As originally defined by von Schelling, it is a synonym of monolatry.  Müller  (the guy who coined "kathenotheism") used it to mean something like summodeism. Edward Wente seems to make the subtle distinction that the monolatrist considers only one god suitable for worship (either because other gods are unworthy, or because of a special relationship to, say, his tribe) whereas the henotheist chooses a preferred god to worship. Either way, thought, there's no chopping and changing: once a henotheist has picked a team, he sticks with it.

So, what then *is* the word for believing in many gods, but worshiping one at a time? It's just polytheism. That is exactly what polytheists actually did. The Romans, for example, had 12 major gods, 12 minor gods, and hundreds of [indigitamenta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigitamenta); the Greeks had even more. No-one can possibly worship more than, at most, one or two at a time! So if you're preparing for the harvest, you offer a sacrifice to Ceres; if it's Bacchanale time, you have a drunken orgy; if you're sick, you offer a cockerel to Asclepius.

Comment: How about Sequentialatry/Sequentheism?

Comment: on Henotheism:: some sources mention Friedrich Gottlieb Welcker, 1784 - 1868, philologist, as another source used by Muller. Is he significant in this group?

Answer (score 4):

Another word for this is [henotheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henotheism), which is very similar to the already-mentioned monolatry. Both are religions where one only worships one God without denying the existence of other gods.

Answer (score 4):

A less complex term might be **serial monotheism**; coined on the model of "serial monogamy". The reason I would prefer this term to many of the linguistically accurate offerings above is that it's immediately clear what is meant, and doesn't leave the reader floundering for a definition.